# How is the JSX-compilation triggered?

Tags: javascript, reactjs, compilation, babeljs, jsx

I'm currently studying React and have set up a simple "Hello, world"-example:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
  <head>
    <meta charset="UTF-8" />
    <title>Hello World</title>
    <script src="https://unpkg.com/react@17/umd/react.development.js"></script>
    <script src="https://unpkg.com/react-dom@17/umd/react-dom.development.js"></script>
    <script src="https://unpkg.com/@babel/standalone/babel.min.js"></script>
  </head>
  <body>
    <div id="root"></div>
    <script type="text/babel">

      ReactDOM.render( 
        <h1>Hello, world!</h1>,
        document.getElementById('root')
      );

    </script>
  </body>
</html>
```

BTW. I deliberately did not use a toolchain like `create-react-app` in order to understand the basics.

The following code snippet is actually something, that a web browser does not understand, because it's not standard JavaScript.

```
ReactDOM.render(<h1>Hello, world!</h1>, document.getElementById('root'));
```

It is JSX (JavaScript Syntax Extension), so it needs to be compiled. For example with Babel.
I know that I included in the head of the html-file the Babel-compiler. **But to me it is unclear when and how the actual compilation process takes place.**

Is there a callback in the Babel-package that is called before the actual rendering and compiles the file in which it was via the `<script src="">`-tag included?

Comment: compilation is done by webpack processing. all jsx are replaced by render function.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The Babel script performs the following:

1. Adds a [`DOMContentLoaded` listener](https://github.com/babel/babel/blob/7250d2562be881f9cdc24c6646468e0f3afcaf9d/packages/babel-standalone/src/index.ts#L209)
2. [Loads all the scripts](https://github.com/babel/babel/blob/7250d2562be881f9cdc24c6646468e0f3afcaf9d/packages/babel-standalone/src/transformScriptTags.ts#L199) if the scripts have a `src`
3. [Transforms the code and injects a `<script>`](https://github.com/babel/babel/blob/7250d2562be881f9cdc24c6646468e0f3afcaf9d/packages/babel-standalone/src/transformScriptTags.ts#L79) to evaluate the newly-transformed code.

Comment: That answers my question. And thanks for the sources.